# Make Py_Main import modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I have a C++ Program in which I call `Py_Main` to get into Python. Now I would like to execute some commands inside of `Py_Main` but cannot seem to figure out how to pass that.

I saw that `Py_Main` calls `Py_Initialize` so I wonder whether it is possible at all.

**EDIT:**

I currently try to do:

```
Py_Initialize();
PyImport_ImportModule("myfoo");

Py_Main(argc, argv);
```

And in `Py_Main` have `myfoo` not available. I can do `import myfoo` then fine.

Comment: If you are embedding Python use the appropriate `C-API` function to run statements, it's called `PyRun_SimpleString` or something like that, can't remember now.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to execute simple commands from C/C++ in Python you should be using the [`PyRun_SimpleString`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/veryhigh.html#c.PyRun_SimpleString) function which takes a `const* char` containing the command to execute.

You shouldn't need to dabble with `Py_Main`, just set the program name and initialize Python with `Py_Initialize` before you call `PyRun_SimpleString`. If you need to import a module and use it you can use [`PyImport_Import`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html#c.PyImport_Import).

Comment: So for some strange reason `PyImport_ImportModule("myfoo")` did not work but `PyRun_SimpleString("import myfoo")` did!?